# Are some accents/dialects incorrect

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, speech, accent

I may not be incorrect in my knowledge about speech, but Dialects or accents that drop sounds from words, syllables from words, or just completely change the sound from words are they correct?

I see pronunciation in the dictionary so by default I assume that is a correct way to pronounce words. Though this may be faulty reasoning.

I've heard many people say that there are millions of way to pronounce something yet whenever I open a dictionary I see the break down on the "standard" way to pronounce words

So I'm wondering if a dialect veers from the standard then are those speaking it speaking correct English?

If an accent veers from a dialect's standard then  are those speaking it speaking correct English?

This may just be a lack of understanding on my part but I endeavor to learn more.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? If there were "incorrect" accents, why would it matter?

Comment: I mean is there an agreed upon standard in terms of pronunciation. Do letters/letter combinations always make the same sound according to the syntax of the English language. Whether it matters or not is unimportant to me just curious.

Comment: It depends on whose agreement you're seeking.

Comment: You lost me. So there is no English standard on pronunciation and speech is fluid, capable of change while still being correct?

Comment: "Standard" is not the same thing as "correct" (and "non-standard" is not the same thing as "incorrect"). For example, [Norwegian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_language) has two main written standards. From what I've heard, it doesn't really have spoken standards. People speak in regional dialects. These are not standardized, but they are not considered "incorrect" either. So you should separate these two concepts.

Comment: Alright, but I suppose I should say, Are there standards on pronunciation and does a deviation from that standard still qualify as "proper" English to the standard? If there is no proper English how can there be standards?

Comment: A standard is just... standard. Standards specify one way of doing something (or a small number of ways). They don't define what is "proper."  For example, "standardized tests" are called that because they're administered in the same, standard way to all students, not because they're the One Proper Way to test students. Other kinds of tests are not "incorrect."

Comment: Sorry for the long string, but how can you have a standard without an agreed upon base? Would it be safer to say that each dialect is proper as long as it has majority agreement and each accent is a variance upon the dialect which may at times constitute as "Broken" English when the variance becomes too great?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you can have a standard without considering everything outside of that standard "incorrect" or "improper."

Comment: A standard has to be based upon an agreed upon foundation otherwise it's nothing more than arrogant self imposed guidelines/law that may have nothing to do with the subject matter. I am trying to find that foundation, if there is a foundation. If there is no foundation than there is no global etiquette so to speak instead everything is regional and left to the dialect meaning pronunciation is fluid and thus the "Properness" would be determined by the regional scope. What may be correct to X may not be correct to Y but it's still correct to X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With regard to the concept of 'correctness' of individual language elements, there are two competing views and these two views will affect how to differentiate varieties.

There is describing scientifically what is out there, what people actually say and how their individual way of speaking can be categorized with others, and then there is systematizing variation, stipulating rules, limiting varieties out of standardizing communication or esthetics.

The first is called descriptivism, the second prescriptivism. Prescriptivism is very much centered on recognizing a single standard; phenomenon X is either 'correct' or not with respect to that single standard. Descriptivism is much more lenient with respect to alternatives and varieties; many varieties can be recognized. Different social registers, ethnicities, localities tend to have within their group consistency such that phenomenon Z is indicative of someone being in a particular group (descriptivists could conceivably use the term 'correct' just allowing many more variations or alterations within a variety). For either -ism, there is a concept of 'this is a phenomenon, but that is not'. However the term 'correct' is socially laden with judgement of other varieties.

'Correctness' is the term used prescriptively for a given standard. Because scientifically there are general groups of people, there are many possible standards. There is a explicit social attempt at imposing standards (dictionaries, schools, media editors, government sanctioned academies).
Many people will say that an Appalachian dialect is not 'correct' when writing newspaper articles, but using "ain't" is 'correct' or 'preferred' when speaking in that variety.

It seems strange to use the word 'correct' for an entire dialect. Is Australian English 'incorrect'? Of course not. Is Appalachian? Well, if you're writing a paper for a conference, it's probably a poor choice for understandability by the conference population.

A dictionary entry displays what should be said and is very likely the most common method *for a particular variety* (for most English dictionaries, it will be either American or British English).

To answer your question more directly, it feels inappropriate to use the term 'correct' for a given dialect out of many. The preferred way of saying it is 'This variety is preferred' and 'Phenomenon X is by far the most common and is accepted as standard (for this particular variety)'.

If you are a school teacher or newspaper editor (who normally only deal with one variety), then you can say 'Phenomenon X is correct'.